# Azure Load Testing: Spin up multiple instances runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, load-testing

I am working on an internal system testing piece of software. Currently it allows our QA to regression test every release which is useful, but we would like to extend it to allow for load testing.

We have decided to explore Azure since it will allow us to spin up multiple instances of our test software and run it from N machines located around the world to load test our servers. I am aware that I can create an azure app that can be uploaded and auto-run on N machines where N is set in the settings file of the Azure app.

What I would like to do is create an MVC website that will server as an interface for our test. From there, you would should be able to select options about which tests to run and other parameters. The part that I don't know if Azure is **capable** of is allowing the user to specify the number of instances to run as well as where the instances should be. The user should be able to then click a button to deploy all those instances. The central problem is dynamically creating and deploying multiple instances of 1 worker role.

My question is if this is possible and if so what might I look into?

Answer (score 2):

Deployments, as well as VM size and instance counts, are controllable by a REST API. There are [PowerShell cmdlets](http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/) built that wrap the API, making these calls rather straightfoward.

So, you can have your MVC app make the appropriate calls to provision your deployments. You probably want your MVC app in its own deployment (maybe a single Extra Small instance, since it really wouldn't do much other than making a few API calls).

Note: There are 6 data centers. For each data center, you'd need a separate deployment DNS name. You can then use the API to deploy to each of the desired data centers, as well as the number of instances within each deployment.